# How to make a div unable to be hovered over?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-hover

I have a navigation menu where if you hover over any of the link items, an animated arrow appears that slightly overlaps the menu.

The problem is that if you mouse over the part of the arrow that is over the menu, the menu's hover state goes away. How do I change this to where the menu's hover state stays active when you mouse over the arrows?

Comment: you need to post some codes... Atleast show us what u hv done...or tried

Answer (score 1):

I think the question core is in difference between mouseenter/mouseover and mouseleave/mouseout events in JQuery.
It looks like you use mouseenter that is not bubbling if cursor points over some element that is over an element you've binded your handler. If I am right, try to replace mouseenter with mouseover event. The same with mouseleave/mouseout pair.
There is a detailed description here:
http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/

Answer (score 0):

You have to use bubbling events as these:

```
$('#mymenu').mouseenter(function(){...})
            .mouseleave(function(){...});
```